# functions of pdb files and PE？

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, reverse-engineering, windbg

I am new in windows programming.

I have learned that the ".pdf" file related to a ".dll" or ".exe" file has some symbols( like addresses of functions、parameters). So I can get the function list from the [".pdb"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) file.

But I also have learned that I can get a ".dll" or ".exe" file's functions infomation by parsing its [PE struct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Import_table)(which contains import tables and export tables related functions of the file)

I want to know what the difference between these two function list I get through two ways above.

Does this equation hold?

eg:"function list from user32.pdb" = "function list from user32.dll's import table and export table"

Comment: No, it doesn't. As their names suggest, the tables in the PE only list functions and variables that are imported or exported, i.e. the information necessary to facilitate dynamic loading. Local variables, functions, and calls to them, are not explicitly documented in the PE. --- By contrast the PDB typically has information about every variable, every function, every type, every enumeration, source file name and line number information for every sequence point, and so on.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for your carefully answer. But I want to know if there are ways to get the full function list of a ".dll" or ".exe" file except parse .pdb in programming.?  Because download  pdb file cost too much time. and PE structure can not provide full function list.

Comment: I think you just gave the answer yourself. Without the PDB, the only other places to look for function names would be the source code itself, or possibly a map file that some compiler emit during compilation - those are typically not distributed outside the dev environment. --- A good disassembler can usually identify functions and variables in a binary module without access to debug information, but it can't infer the original names of said functions.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for you reply. I need to transfer the function address which is gotten from the Windows log tools to the function name. So I need to get full function list to map from address to function name.  Maybe I failed to implement this function in my program.. lol

Answer (score 0):

A `.pdb` file is more than just a list outward visible functions. It may carry a whole slew of debugging information, that's being stripped from a release binary.

Say you're a developer who wants to debug a program crash, or single step a process created from a release binary. For that to work, the debugger needs some way to connect the amorphous blob that is a stripped release binary, with the original source files and annotate the running process image with symbol information. `.pdb` files carry that information, that goes beyond mere exported symbols.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My purpose is to get the function address list of the .dll file in my program with C++ language. But I find there are two methods(parse PE structure or .pdb file) to get the list. I find I can get more functions from .pdb . I wonder why .pdb file contain more functions than PE

Comment: and my first chioce is to parse PE structure. Because it dose not need to download .pdb files., which means it performs faster than parsing .pdb file. But the function list from this way is less than .pdb file, even I get both the import table and export table of PE structure., the function list is still less than parse .pdb file.

Comment: imports and exports are normally documented functions an exported function foo() can call many functions internally and thier names types arguments calling conventions returns etc will be available in pdb and not in header

Comment: @Q_7iu: The symbol tables exported by a DLL usually is just a (very) small subset of all the symbols and functions that make up the DLL. Say you're developing a library that's calculating the volume of 3D objects: The public facing functions would consist of a way to load the 3D model and maybe some scaling factor and returns a single value; but internally the library has to do a lot of things, split the model down into manageable chunks, check topology, etc. Nothing of that needs to be exported. But for debugging the whereabouts are need to be known.

Comment: @Q_7iu: Maybe this helps: A DLL's exports are like transit stations / airports. You as a passenger are just getting on and off from these well known points. A PDB is a detailed map of everything that's relevant to the pilots like traffic control, topography, navigation points, etc.

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you for your patient answer! What a good metaphor! It really helps me a lot! Can I understand this as following? The exports function list from PE are some "public function" from .pdb that are open to other .exe or .dll to use. The other function list from .pdb are "private function" which are not  exposed to be called by other programs. So the exports function always are less than pdb.

Comment: @blabb Thanks for your nice answer! I think I have already known the connection between them. Thank appreciatively!